# Resizing Image and fit it to the Canvas size

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, python-imaging-library

Can anyone help me to resize the image using ImageTk?

I have a canvas and I will put pictures there.

I have different kinds of pictures = different sizes for all pictures

And when I attach the picture (just one) in the canvas, I want the picture's size to resize so that it will fit in the canvas and it will still maintain its proportion.

Please help me! I am new in PIL, Tkinter,and Python.

Update:

I tried using `thumbnail` under `Image` but in resizing:

```
self.image.thumbnail(self.picsize,Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

the image is not fitting the canvas size and if the image is longer/wider than the canvas, it is just cut. (Not resizing to fit into the canvas)

---

Code:

```
from PIL import ImageTk
from Tkinter import *
import os,tkFileDialog,Image

picsize = 250,250 # I want to set this so that it will fit in the self.imagecanvas | Every images attached will share same Size
imagepath = "Default_ProPic.jpg"
class GUI():
    global picsize
    def display(self):
        self.canvas = Canvas(width=1200,height=700)
        self.canvas.pack()
    
        self.imagecanvas = Canvas(self.canvas,width=400,height=400)
        self.imagecanvas.place(x=980,y=180)
        self.image = Image.open(imagepath)
        self.image.thumbnail(picsize,Image.ANTIALIAS)
        self.newimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        self.profile_picture=self.imagecanvas.create_image(0,0,anchor = NW,image=self.newimage)
    
        attachbutton = Button(self.canvas,text="       Profile Pic       ",command=lambda:self.attachpic())
        attachbutton.place(x=1030,y=320)
    
        mainloop()

    def attachpic(self):
        global picsize
        attachphoto = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(title="Attach photo")
        self.image = Image.open(attachphoto)
        self.image.thumbnail(picsize,Image.ANTIALIAS)
        self.newimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        self.imagecanvas.itemconfigure(self.profile_picture, image=self.newimage)
    
GUI = GUI()
GUI.display()
```

---

Picture used above: [image]

Comment: here's [slideshow application implemented in Tkinter. It resize images to fit inside the app. window](https://gist.github.com/zed/8b05c3ea0302f0e2c14c)

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the thumbnail as a separate variable:

```
self.thmb_img = self.image.thumbnail(picsize, Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

I suspect it may be taking the original `self.image = Image.open(attachphoto)`

I would suggest watching what sizing is going on with:

```
def attachpic(self):
    picsize = 250, 250
    attachphoto = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(title="Attach photo")
    self.image = Image.open(attachphoto)
    print self.image.size()
    self.thmb_img = self.image.thumbnail(picsize,Image.ANTIALIAS)
    print self.thmb_img.size()
```

Check the output size and verify it is the same as the original and the desired (250, 250) thumbnail.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is figure out the size you should resize to while

- Making it all fit inside the window, and
- Preserving the original aspect ratio.

Thankfully that's not hard to do.

```
 def best_fit(oldsize, picsize):
    new_width, new_height = picsize
    old_width, old_height = oldsize
    # if new_width/old_width < new_height/old_height is mathematically the same as
    if new_width * old_height < new_height * old_width:
        # reduce height to keep original aspect ratio
        new_height = max(1, old_height * new_width // old_width)
    else:
        # reduce width to keep original aspect ratio
        new_width = max(1, old_width * new_height // old_height)
    return (new_width, new_height)

siz = self.image.size
self.image = self.image.resize(best_fit(siz, picsize), Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

The `max` calls keep the width and height from going to zero.